# Template data member

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class

```
class Store
{
    template <int N> using map = std::unordered_map<typename Topo<N>::type*, std::unique_ptr<Node<N>>>;
    template <int N> map<N>& get();
    
    map<0> m_0;
    template <> map<0>& get<0>() { return m_0; }
    map<1> m_1;
    template <> map<1>& get<1>() { return m_1; }
      // ...
    map<7> m_7;
    template <> map<7>& get<7>() { return m_7; }
};
```

I am looking for a way to avoid to repeat the declaration of the variables. Probably it is possible to do something with integer sequences, but I cannot figure out the syntax.

Comment: "Write compact, elegant code" - yes, human =D

Comment: the code does not compile, hence it is unclear what or why you want to repeat. https://godbolt.org/z/3ee6Pbo8x

Comment: oh well.... looking at the formatted code It makes kind of sense...

Comment: there is no need for the getters. Make the members public

Comment: You'll need a tuple, since you can't generate variable names. Then getters become unnecessary, as you can `std::get<i>(...)` the tuple.

Answer (score 4):

How about putting them in a heterogeneous array (i.e. tuple)?

```
class Store
{
public:
template <int N> using map = std::unordered_map<typename Topo<N>::type*, std::unique_ptr<Node<N>>>;
template <int N> map<N>& get();

std::tuple<map<0>, map<1>, ..., map<7>> maps;
};


Store store;
auto& m_1 = std::get<1>(store.maps);
...
```

You can have a getter if you want:

```
template<int N>
const auto& get_map() const {
  return std::get<N>(maps);
}
```

Comment: This is better, but still has boilerplate. You can generate the tuple type using `std::make_index_sequence`.

Comment: I honestly think using `std::make_index_sequence` in this case is over-engineering.

Comment: over-engineering maybe, but with your solution the difference is that now they have to write `std::tuple<map<0>, map<1>, ..., map<7>> maps;` instead of `map<0> m0; map<1> m1; .... map<7> m7;`. Its not really less repetition than in the original code (modulo the getters, which they don't really need)

Comment: It's N times less since they have to declare one field instead of N. And they might actually need the getters for e.g. const access.

Comment: they have to declare N types to spell out the tuple.

Comment: dont get me wrong, I think your solution is completely ok. It does require O(N) typing though

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: creating the generator from index_sequence also add some code (which might be considered harder to understand by beginners too)...

Comment: @Jarod42 sure. Its a trade off. Theres a turning point N_x where understanding the additional code takes less time than spelling out N_x types. I suppose its safe to assume that N_x >> 7 ;)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by HolyBlackCat, you can use `std::make_index_sequence` to declare a `std::tuple< map<0> , map<1> ,... map<N>>`. You do not need getters. When they return non-const references you can make the members public.

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <int N> struct Foo {};

template <typename X> struct foo_tuple_impl;    
template <int...I> struct foo_tuple_impl< std::integer_sequence<int,I...> > {
    using type = std::tuple< Foo<I> ...>;
};    
template <int N> struct foo_tuple {
    using type = typename foo_tuple_impl< std::make_integer_sequence<int,N> >::type;
};    
template <int N> using foo_tuple_t = typename foo_tuple<N>::type;

struct Storage {
    foo_tuple_t<8> map;
};
```